# php include class with the same name but other namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I am having two classes with the same name but different namespace. In both instances, the class is named `User`.

- NameSpace 1: DAL
- NameSpace 2: Logic

Folder structure:

```
-Site
  --DAL
  --Logic
```

A method/function within the class User within the namespace Logic uses a method/function that is in the class User within the namespace DAL.

But everytime I try to include the class I get the error message: 
`Uncaught Error: Class 'Logic\DAL\User' not found`.

I tried:

```
require_once("../DAL/User.class.php")
require_once(__DIR__ . "USer.class.php")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you referring to the mentioned classes? Please show us the code, that triggers the error message

Comment: I get the error when I try to run a method from DAL user class when being in the Logic user class, example: if (!DAL\User::Validate($mail, $password)) { return false; }

Comment: Any reason to not import? (`use`) - also, is the uppercase `U` a typo in your post  `USer.class.php`? SIDE:  drop the brackets around the requires, they're language constructs not functions ;)